# Can Google bot index pages built with websocket if I implement dynamic rendering?

Tags: google-search, googlebot, googlebot-mobile

This is the first time I build a website so I did not know anything about SEO when I started. I built many pages of my website to be rendered by React + Redux with the data received from websocket (initially my page is a html (a div essentially), then when websocket is open, depending on the URL, websocket will send message to my server to retrieve data and then the browser will re-render with the received data). Everything works fine but now I learn that Googlebot does not index contents from websocket.

I really don't want to rebuild my whole infrastructure so I did some research. I found a page from Google about [dynamic rendering with Rendertron](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/01/dynamic-rendering-with-rendertron). It seems like what dynamic rendering does is it gets data from the server then serves HTML to Googlebot. I wonder whether I can use dynamic rendering to help Googlebot crawl the pages I build using websocket? Thanks

Comment: Websockets are usually used for pushing updates to pages after they are loaded.  Did you use websockets for loading the page initially?  That isn't what they are designed for.

Comment: Initially my page is a html (a div essentially), then when websocket is open, depending on the URL, websocket will send message to my server to retrieve data

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using websockets like that.   How hard would it be to convert the websocket to AJAX?   AJAX is good a fetching the initial page load and has better browser and crawler support.

Comment: It's doable but it will require much work. Thanks for your answer. I did some more research and it seems like there is no other way except to convert the websocket to fetch/AJAX. I have only been using fetch but not AJAX. Do you know whether Googlebot can crawl contents from fetch?

Comment: I'm not sure what "fetch" is.   AJAX is pretty simple compared to websockets.  It doesn't require a continuous connection to the server or having the server run `ws:` or `wss:` protocols.   In general it is much easier to implement and run in a variety of environments.

Comment: oh this is fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API